# Jasmine tests - providing test cases

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jasmine

I just started to use `jasmine` (version 2.4.1) to test my `javascript` code. Working in `Visual Studio 2015`. I have a function which I would like to check for multiple inputs - like `TestCase` in `nUnit`.

Small example:

The function I would like to test:

```
this.daysInMonth = function(month, year) {
   return new Date(year, month + 1, 0).getDate();
}
```

This is my test file:

```
/// <reference path="~/bin/Debug/Content/js/knockout.js" />
/// <reference path="~/bin/Debug/Content/js/reporttimefilter/ReportTimeFilter.js" />
/// <reference path="~/Scripts/jasmine/jasmine-every.js" />

var numOfDaysTestcases = [
    { year: 2016, month: 9, expectedDays: 31 },
    { year: 2016, month: 1, expectedDays: 29 }
];

every(numOfDaysTestcases, function (index, testcase) {
    describe('each test case', function () {
        var report;

        beforeEach(function () {
            report = new ReportFilterViewModel();
        });

        it('get current month number of day', function () {
            expect(report.daysInMonth(testcase.year, testcase.month)).toBe(testcase.expectedDays);
        });
    });
});
```

The example is based on this [link](https://github.com/Jon-Biz/jasmine-every). When I run my tests I get

> No specs found

in the chrome tab that opens and a

> Inconclusive: Test not run

as the test result.

The following test using only one object works and is successful - so I figure it is something with the `every` function:

```
describe('each test case', function () {
    var report;

    beforeEach(function () {
       report = new ReportFilterViewModel();
    });

    var testcase = { year: 2016, month: 9, expectedDays: 31 };

    it('get current month number of day', function () {
       expect(report.daysInMonth(testcase.year, testcase.month)).toBe(testcase.expectedDays);
    });
});
```

My question is what did I do wrong? What did I miss?

Comment: Dit you install the *jasmine-every* package? 
```npm install jasmine-every```

Comment: I added the script from the link I provided in the question to the `Scripts/jasmine` folder. I'll try the install. I forgot to mention, I am working in VS2015 on Windows

Comment: May be you could use the second method described in this article, which is more or less the same as how your current library works (or to be precise, doesn't).
http://www.ontestautomation.com/data-driven-javascript-tests-using-jasmine/

Comment: I tried both approaches in this link, however non of them seem to work for me. The tests start but are always in running mode.

Comment: I just also tried the second method and it works fine. I'm running from the command line however, not from within Visual Studio. What do you mean by 'are always in running mode'? Do you mean the status in the VS Test Explorer window?

Comment: I just installed the Chutzpah test runner and all works fine in Visual Studio 2015 as well here.